# Where to add a mapping in the Velocity Context?

Tags: jira, velocity

After a little digging, I found that Velocity Context is a mapping (Keys -> Value). Now I want to create a new variable (or a new mapping) in the Velocity Context so I can access it *.vm files the same way I can access the Default Velocity context variables mentionned here 
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Velocity+Context+for+Email+Templates

I understand I need to do something like this

 VelocityParams.put("commentManager", ComponentManager.getInstance().getCommentManager());

My question is where to add this ? (i.e: Where Velocity Context is initialized?)

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to get access to some variables that not available by default in the Velocity Context (take Component Accessor for example). But I found a way to instantiate it inside the VM files thanks to https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/237939/jira-6-velocity-how-to-retrieve-context

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to be able to use some services in velocity you need to pass it to template. The best place would be just before displaying template.
You can use:

```
org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext params = new VelocityContext(com.atlassian.jira.util.JiraVelocityUtils.getDefaultVelocityParams(authenticationContext));
```

or if you need just Map:

```
Map<String, Object> params = JiraVelocityUtils.getDefaultVelocityParams(authenticationContext);
```

Where JIRA authentication context is autowired class com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraAuthenticationContext